# How to Dynamically add spaces in PHP

Tags: php

I have this data array:

```
 [0] => 15 10 010   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm   900mm x 15m   ROLL   22.0
[1] => 15 10 020   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm  1200mm x 15m   ROLL   29.0
[2] => 15 10 030   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm  1500mm x 15m   ROLL   36.0
[3] => 15 10 040   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm x 1800mm x 15m   ROLL   43.0
[4] => 15 10 050   Chainmesh Galv  50 x 2.50mm  2400mm x 15m   ROLL   54.0
[5] => 15 10 055   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm x 3000mm x 15M   ROLL   71.0
[6] => 15 20 010   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 3.15mm  1200mm x 15m   ROLL   48.0
[7] => 15 20 020   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 3.15mm  1800mm x 15m   ROLL   72.0
```

And i need to have this output in dropdown menu:
   http://screencast.com/t/kWkUuBlq
   Please see the spacing of the dropdown, that's my problem.

For now  I have this line of code:

```
 foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
        $data3 = explode('   ', $value);
        for ($i=0; $i < count($data3) -1 ; $i++) { 
            echo $data3[$i];
        }
    }
```

I tried exploding the array element and store it again in new array with a spacing same with the image but, it gives me the same little spacing. Thank you.

Comment: How about to use HTML? It was invented just because of such problems

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
        $data3 = explode(' ', $value);
        $tempData = array();
        for ($i=0; $i < count($data3); $i++) { 
            if(trim($data3[$i]) != ''){
                $tempData[] = trim($data3[$i]);
            }
        }
$array2[$key] = implode(' ', $tempData);
}
print_r($array2);
    ?>
```

Out put:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15 10 010 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm 900mm x 15m ROLL 22.0
    [1] => 15 10 020 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm 1200mm x 15m ROLL 29.0
    [2] => 15 10 030 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm 1500mm x 15m ROLL 36.0
    [3] => 15 10 040 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm x 1800mm x 15m ROLL 43.0
    [4] => 15 10 050 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm 2400mm x 15m ROLL 54.0
    [5] => 15 10 055 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm x 3000mm x 15M ROLL 71.0
    [6] => 15 20 010 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 3.15mm 1200mm x 15m ROLL 48.0
    [7] => 15 20 020 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 3.15mm 1800mm x 15m ROLL 72.0
)
```

Comment: @Alma Do. Actually the dropdown is populated in jquery, so I need to have the spacing in PHP. I used AJAX  here that's why you can see the echo line. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this to convert in HTML and then use some CSS to give the actual look that you want.

```
function insertHTML( $val ){
   return "<td>" . $val . "</td>";
}

// your array
$array2 = array(
    "15 10 010   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm   900mm x 15m   ROLL   22.0", 
    "15 10 020   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm   1200mm x 15m   ROLL   29.0");

$html = "";
foreach( $array2 as $val ){
  $array_line =  explode("   ", $val);
  $htmlArr = array_map( "insertHTML", $array_line );
  $html .= "<tr>\n" . implode( "\n", $htmlArr ) . "\n</tr>\n";
}

echo "<table>\n";
echo $html;
echo "</table>";
```

#### OutPut:

http://codepad.org/gWKMtMPv

#### Note:

You can't achieve that if you don't have proper spacing that you are using to explode the string with `explode()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
    <?php
    $a = array (0 => '15 10 010   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm   900mm x 15m   ROLL   22.0',
1 => '15 10 020   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm  1200mm x 15m   ROLL   29.0',
2=> '15 10 030   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm  1500mm x 15m   ROLL   36.0',
3 => '15 10 040   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm x 1800mm x 15m   ROLL   43.0',
4 => '15 10 050   Chainmesh Galv  50 x 2.50mm  2400mm x 15m   ROLL   54.0',
5 => '15 10 055   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm x 3000mm x 15M   ROLL   71.0',
6 => '15 20 010   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 3.15mm  1200mm x 15m   ROLL   48.0',
7 => '15 20 020   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 3.15mm  1800mm x 15m   ROLL   72.0');
foreach($a as $key => $v){
echo '['.$key.']' .'='. preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $v).'<br>';  
}
?>
```

Output like

```
[0]=15 10 010 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm 900mm x 15m ROLL 22.0
[1]=15 10 020 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm 1200mm x 15m ROLL 29.0
[2]=15 10 030 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm 1500mm x 15m ROLL 36.0
[3]=15 10 040 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm x 1800mm x 15m ROLL 43.0
[4]=15 10 050 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm 2400mm x 15m ROLL 54.0
[5]=15 10 055 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm x 3000mm x 15M ROLL 71.0
[6]=15 20 010 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 3.15mm 1200mm x 15m ROLL 48.0
[7]=15 20 020 Chainmesh Galv 50 x 3.15mm 1800mm x 15m ROLL 72.0
```

HTML Dropdown example

```
<?php
$a = array (0 => '15 10 010   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm   900mm x 15m   ROLL   22.0',
1 => '15 10 020   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm  1200mm x 15m   ROLL   29.0',
2=> '15 10 030   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm  1500mm x 15m   ROLL   36.0',
3 => '15 10 040   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm x 1800mm x 15m   ROLL   43.0',
4 => '15 10 050   Chainmesh Galv  50 x 2.50mm  2400mm x 15m   ROLL   54.0',
5 => '15 10 055   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 2.50mm x 3000mm x 15M   ROLL   71.0',
6 => '15 20 010   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 3.15mm  1200mm x 15m   ROLL   48.0',
7 => '15 20 020   Chainmesh Galv 50 x 3.15mm  1800mm x 15m   ROLL   72.0');
echo '<select>';

foreach($a as $key => $v){
echo '<option value="'.$key.'">' . preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $v).'</option>';
}
echo '<select>';
?>
```